# Difference between UnknownHostException and UnresolvedAddressException

Tags: java, dns

I've encountered these two exceptions in turn but in slightly different contexts and I am not sure what the situational differences are.

From the Javadocs, I understand that the UnknownHostException is when a DNS lookup fails: hostname => IP address fails.

From the Javadocs, UnresolvedAddressException:

> Unchecked exception thrown when an attempt is made to invoke a network operation upon an unresolved socket address.

What does resolution mean in this context? The mapping from hostname to IP?

My hypothesis right now regarding the difference is that UHE (UnknownHostException) would be thrown upon any failed lookup from a hostname to an IP using either the local mappings (like `/etc/hosts` or DNS) and UAE (UnresolvedAddressException) would occur when we store a reference to a network name without looking up what IP it translates to and then try to do something with it, like connect via HTTP.

Does this sound correct? The weird thing is that sometimes during network issues, this would occur interchangeably in some code so I was not sure of the difference.

Comment: can you show the code that produced the 2 exceptions?

Comment: I've never even seen an `UnresolvedAddressException`, in nearly 18 years of Java. It's undoubtedly relevant that it is part of `java.nio.channels,` not `java.net.` It seems to arise from misuse of a `SocketAddress.`

Comment: `UnresolvedAddressException` is what socket connections get instead of `UnknownHostException`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42306951/3777824 . Basically  the name resolution works a bit differently for sockets for reasons I am still trying to understand.