# How does DNS work with Java Sockets?

Tags: java, sockets, dns

My question feels kind of basic, and yet it has made me curious for a while:

Does using the name of a server instead of its IP address work when using a Java Socket?

For example, if I am the manager of a certain server with the address "bogusserver.com" and use this address instead of the actual IP of the server when opening the Socket with a 'new Socket("bogusserver.com", 8080);' will it actually open the socket normally?

If it does, how exactly does the Socket class solve the address? Does it use the DNS server registered at the computer running the code?

I know that using the "localhost" address the Socket will open normally, but then, everything works with localhost :P

Comment: *Does using the name of a server instead of its IP address work when using a Java Socket?* why don't you just try? Or just read the javadoc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to read the javadoc. A [Socket is constructed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) using an InetAddress.

The [InetAddress javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html) says:

> Host name-to-IP address resolution is accomplished through the use of a combination of local machine configuration information and network naming services such as the Domain Name System (DNS) and Network Information Service(NIS). The particular naming services(s) being used is by default the local machine configured one. For any host name, its corresponding IP address is returned.

Answer (score 2):

> Does using the name of a server instead of its IP address work when using a Java Socket?

DNS maybe used by the OS to translate the hostname into an IP address. It doesn't matter if you use TCP, UDP or ICMP.

> If it does, how exactly does the Socket class solve the address?

It passes it to the OS to do the lookup.

> Does it use the DNS server registered at the computer running the code?

The OS has registered DNS servers and they may be contacted if there isn't a `hosts` entry for that hostname.